# 502 bad gateway error when deploying to nginx web server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I built a react app using the `create-react-app` and `npm run build`commands and connected it to node with `server.js`file in the directory created by `create-react-app`.

When running the command `node server` locally it works perfectly fine however when I pushed the changes to my nginx server I started to get a 502 bad gateway status. Why is this happening? Node is running when I get this error.

Here is the `server.js` code

```
onst express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();


app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , '/public/build')));


// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , "/public/build/index.html"));

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

the error log

```
[error] 7422#7422: *4477 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.84.158.175, server: anthonyjimenez.me, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "anthonyjimenez.me"
```

and the config file

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: I think 502 bad gateway means that nginx cannot forward the request to the server, in this case because nginx cannot connect to it...

Answer (score 0):

go to /nginx/sites-enabled/default and add the following blocks. You will have to tell Nginx and forward this request this way

```
server {

listen 443 ssl ;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; //ssl
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; //ssl

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name example.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3001; //Your port goes here
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}


}
```